# How to center a rotated child div to a rotated parent div and stick to the top of parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hopefully, my question is easy to understand. I've created a codepen to better show what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a big diamond shape (actual shapen is rectangular) and using CSS I rotate them to make a diamond shape. I then put a small image (which I rotate also) on top of the image and stick the second image to the top center of the main image.

This work well for desktop and tablet but the issue I'm having is when viewing on mobile. Since there are many different sizes of mobile width, the second image (the orange color) get cut off when viewing on iPhone 8 but look perfect on iPhone X.

I know I can target media query for different devices but I don't think that will work as there are way too many mobile sizes.

I think the most logical is to find the second image div to make it center horizontally? but since it is rotated, there is no way for me to find them.

Any suggestion will help. Thank you guys.

[image: iPhone 8]

[image: iPhone X]

```
<div class="box"> 

<div class="diamond-content space-default">
        <div class="diamond-shape">
  <div class="bg"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQ2RMQ3m/sample.jpg" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="logo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jSPtc1Z5/sample2.png" class="img-fluid"></div>
        </div>
          <div class="diamond-shape">
  <div class="bg"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQ2RMQ3m/sample.jpg" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="logo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jSPtc1Z5/sample2.png" class="img-fluid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.box {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.diamond-content {
    position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
      max-width: 1200px;

}

.diamond-shape {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .diamond-shape {
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .diamond-shape {
        width: 420px;
        height: 420px;
    }

    .diamond-shape.right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 -100px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .diamond-shape {
        width: 480px;
        height: 480px;
    }
}

/*Content Inside Diamond*/


.diamond-shape img {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}


.diamond-shape .logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: -12px 0 0 132px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .diamond-shape .logo {
        width: 120px;
        margin: -18px 0 0 248px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .diamond-shape .logo {
        width: 130px;
        margin: -20px 0 0 310px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .diamond-shape .logo {
        width: 150px;
        margin: -22px 0 0 352px;
    }
}

.diamond-shape .bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 302px;
    margin: -57px 0px 0 -57px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .diamond-shape .bg {
        width: 510px;
        margin: -100px 0px 0 -100px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .diamond-shape .bg {
        width: 680px;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RXVjog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your whole CSS with this one and the orange diamond (.logo) will always be at the center top because it is set to position absolute and right 0.

Here's fixed [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/lakialex/pen/LwyeOm) https://codepen.io/lakialex/pen/LwyeOm

```
.box {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.diamond-content {
    position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
      max-width: 1200px;

}

.diamond-shape {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .diamond-shape {
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .diamond-shape {
        width: 420px;
        height: 420px;
    }

    .diamond-shape.right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 -100px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .diamond-shape {
        width: 480px;
        height: 480px;
    }
}

/*Content Inside Diamond*/


.diamond-shape img {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}




.diamond-shape .bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 302px;
    margin: -57px 0px 0 -57px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .diamond-shape .bg {
        width: 510px;
        margin: -100px 0px 0 -100px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .diamond-shape .bg {
        width: 680px;
    }
}

.diamond-shape .logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -11px;
    margin-top: -11px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .diamond-shape .logo {
        width: 120px;
        margin-right: -17px;
        margin-top: -17px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .diamond-shape .logo {
        width: 130px;
        margin-right: -17px;
        margin-top: -17px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .diamond-shape .logo {
        width: 150px;
        margin-right: -21px;
        margin-top: -21px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lazar Momcilovic, Thank you so much, your solutions seem to solve the problem. But do you mind explaining to me a bit more so I can learn? Is it because I rotate the div that's why I have to use right 0? Why Left 0 does not work?

Comment: Exactly, if you remove the rotation you'll see that the default position is left so placing right: 0 makes it always right and the when you apply transform rotation then it's at the top. Cheers!

Comment: Thank @Lazar Momcilovic, I try to follow your concept but I don't seem to be able to get it to work for the text. I also need the text to be center but they just don't seem to work. Thought I understood it but don't seem like it. I've updated the condepen to include the text. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RXVjog. I know I'm asking too much here but I'm totally confuse now.

Comment: I've updated my CodePen fork https://codepen.io/lakialex/pen/LwyeOm
The text element .subhead class needed different solution, simple flexbox with center alignment for both vertical and horizontal will do and it will be always centered no matter the transform, rotation or not. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Set a min-width and min-height to diamond shape.

```
min-width: 200px;
min-height: 200px;
```

Comment: The problem with me putting min-width is that the two diamond will not be center in the view when you go from iPhone X and other iPhone or mobile with different sizes.

Comment: Check @Sunil answer, it will help you. Add `margin: auto;` to diamond content

Answer (score 0):

> Add this for center div

```
.diamond-content {
position: relative;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: auto;
```

}